# How to check if one or more strings contained in string1 using javascript

Tags: javascript, methods

I write this function but it only worked with one string ,

```
 contains(input,words) {
      let input1 = input.split(' ');
      for ( var i = 0; i < input1.length; i++ ) { 
      if (input1[i] === words) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
        }
      }
     }



let contains = Str.prototype.contains('hello me want coffee','hello');
```

will return true

how to make it work with several words

```
let contains = Str.prototype.contains('hello me want coffe',['hello','want']);
```

Comment: does your code really work? what is, if the wanted word is not the first one? the early exit in the first iteration makes it impossible to get the wanted result.

Comment: Do it in two nested loops. the Outer one should be on the "words" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `some` method in combination with `split`.

```js
let contains = (str, arr) => str.split(' ').some(elem => arr.includes(elem));
console.log(contains('hello me want coffe',['hello','want']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method along with the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method, instead of your `contains()`:

```js
console.log(['hello', 'want'].some(x => 'hello me want coffe'.includes(x)));
console.log(['hello', 'want'].some(x => 'me want coffe'.includes(x)));
console.log(['hello', 'want'].some(x => 'me coffe'.includes(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `indexOf()` logic

```js
function contains(input, words) {
       length = words.length;
    while(length--) {
       if (input.indexOf(words[length])!=-1) {
          return true;
       }else{
         return false;
       }  
      }  
     }


console.log(contains('hello me want coffe',['hello','want']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` to look for the strings. The pro to use `RegExp` is that you can be case insensitive.

```js
// 'i' means you are case insensitive
const contains = (str, array) => array.some(x => new RegExp(x, 'i').test(str));

const arr = [
  'hello',
  'want',
];

console.log(contains('hello me want coffe', arr));
console.log(contains('HELLO monsieur!', arr));
console.log(contains('je veux des croissants', arr));
```